# Why did Spock ask McCoy to help him reconfigure a torpedo?

Tags: star-trek, character-motivation, the-undiscovered-country

I don't understand how/why McCoy would be able to help with the torpedo setup. He's a doctor, not an engineer.

Comment: Perhaps they needed his steady hands.

Comment: "He's a doctor, not an engineer" — you've missed a "_Damnit_, Jim" in there.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_suzpmJ8nGc

Comment: @OrangeDog Next you’ll be claiming that Kirk never said “Beam me up, Scotty”.

Comment: In real-life navies, people cross-train quite a bit. The cook can probably work a machine gun or assist with damage control.

Comment: The same question and answer applies to *Into Darkness* (ew)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We get a little more info (and a different version of the dialogue) in the film's [*official novelisation*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country_(novel)). In short, McCoy evidently has a reasonable knowledge of the systems involved and the best person for the job, Scott, is otherwise occupied. Plus it's fiddly work and he's got surgeon's hands.

> Kirk finished. "Precisely. They may be unable to completely cloak the exhaust products of their impulse engines. But accurate targeting will prove difficult." Kirk did not quite smile. "The portable equipment in the science lab, for atmospheric analysis . . ."
>
> Spock nodded. The doctor's eyes widened as he looked from the Vulcan to the captain and back.
>
> "That's it, then," McCoy said cheerfully.
>
> "Pretty delicate work, though, and Scotty's tied up in Engineering right now." He started for the lift. "I'm going to perform surgery on a torpedo. You never know. . ." Spock glanced at the captain and, after receiving a nod, accompanied McCoy. "You may need assistance, Doctor."
>
> As the lift doors snapped open, McCoy gave the Vulcan a sly glance. "Fascinating. .

Comment: When do you think was the last time McCoy did actual surgery?

Comment: @MarkRansom - It's not all lasers, you know.

Comment: @MarkRansom Does rocket surgery not count?

Comment: @user253751 No, but brain science does.

Comment: @DJClayworth but he was augmented when he did that.

Comment: @Valorum It is also pills.

Comment: @MarkRansom Other than the ham-fisted field medicine with Gorkon, I'd say it was probably in San Fransisco, 1986 - Chekov's subdural hematoma.

Answer (score 11):

In the movie, the other characters think that Mccoy can do it because they compare it to doing surgery on a torpedo. While he may not know how the torpedo works, he has enough experience manipulating fine components and he has the *guidance* of other Starfleet personnel.